# How to choose between FE and BE model

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am reading the book:

> Baum, C. F. (2006). An Introduction to Modern Econometrics Using Stata
>   (Stata Press, ed.).

In particular Chapter 9 treats panel data and explains the Fixed Effect (FE) models and the Between Estimator (BE) model.

At a certain point there is written:

> With panel data, we can identify whether the interesting sources of
>   variation are in individuals’ variation around their means or in those
>   means themselves. The within estimator takes account of only the
>   former, whereas the between estimator considers only the latter.

But it doesn't explain how to do that. How do I choose from a FE model rather than a BE model?

I know there is the Hausman test to choose between FE and Random Effects (RE). Is there such a test to choose between FE and BE too?

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that you would ever want to choose between these two extremes. You would likely only go with a BE model if 90%+ of the variance (as indexed by the intraclass correlation coefficient) is between units (just pulling a number out of thin air here).

Alternatively, you can use a RE model to get both the within and between coefficients in the same model.

For each predictor that varies within clusters, calculate the mean of that variable for each cluster:

`bysort cluster: egen cmn_x = mean(x)`

Then run the RE model:

`xtreg y x cmn_x, i(cluster) re`

The coefficient for `cmn_x` is the difference in size of the coefficient of the between effect relative to the within effect. The test of significance for `cmn_x` tells you whether the between effect is different from the within effect. You can easily recover the pure between effect:

`lincom x + cmn_x`

As an exmaple, we can use the admissions.dta from the Stata 15 manual, which has data on admissions from a set of departments within a university:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r15/admissions.dta, clear 
describe 


Contains data from http://www.stata-press.com/data/r15/admissions.dta
  obs:            46                          Graduate school admissions data
 vars:             5                          25 Feb 2016 09:28
 size:           644                          (_dta has notes)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------              
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
department      long    %8.0g      dept       department id
nadmitted       byte    %8.0g                 number of admissions
napplied        float   %9.0g                 number of applications
female          byte    %8.0g                 =1 if female, =0 if male
```

The between effect model predicting # of admissions from # applied:

```
xtreg nadmitted napplied, i(department) be

Between regression (regression on group means)  Number of obs     =         46
Group variable: department                      Number of groups  =         23

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.7392                                         min =          2
     between = 0.4398                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.5302                                         max =          2

                                                F(1,21)           =      16.49
sd(u_i + avg(e_i.))=  7.859423                  Prob > F          =     0.0006

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   nadmitted |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    napplied |    .180098   .0443518     4.06   0.001     .0878634    .2723326
       _cons |   7.719926   2.586917     2.98   0.007     2.340136    13.09971
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now the within effect:

```
xtreg nadmitted napplied, i(department) fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =         46
Group variable: department                      Number of groups  =         23

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.7392                                         min =          2
     between = 0.4398                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.5302                                         max =          2

                                                F(1,22)           =      62.37
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.2430                        Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   nadmitted |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    napplied |   .2428959   .0307572     7.90   0.000     .1791093    .3066825
       _cons |    4.88583   1.594119     3.06   0.006     1.579828    8.191831
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  8.0368968
     sigma_e |  5.3163754
         rho |  .69561491   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(22, 22) = 4.30                      Prob > F = 0.0006
```

Now put them together in the RE model (switching to mixed for REML b/c of small sample size), first calculating the cluster mean of `napplied`:

```
bysort department: egen cmn_app=mean(napplied)

mixed nadmitted napplied cmn_app || department:, reml

Mixed-effects REML regression                   Number of obs     =         46
Group variable: department                      Number of groups  =         23

                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          2
                                                              avg =        2.0
                                                              max =          2

                                                Wald chi2(2)      =      78.85
Log restricted-likelihood = -160.93643          Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   nadmitted |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    napplied |   .2428959   .0307572     7.90   0.000     .1826128    .3031789
     cmn_app |  -.0627979    .053973    -1.16   0.245    -.1685831    .0429873
       _cons |   7.719926   2.586918     2.98   0.003      2.64966    12.79019
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Random-effects Parameters  |   Estimate   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
department: Identity         |
                  var(_cons) |   47.63861    19.5332       21.3276    106.4085
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------
               var(Residual) |   28.26384   8.521869      15.65252    51.03618
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. linear model: chibar2(01) = 10.87         Prob >= chibar2 = 0.0005
```

Recover the pure between effect:

```
lincom napplied+cmn_app

 ( 1)  [nadmitted]napplied + [nadmitted]cmn_app = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   nadmitted |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |    .180098   .0443518     4.06   0.000     .0931701    .2670259
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There you have it! One model to get both effects and a test of whether the between effect is different than the within effect.